# Workflow 4.5 Dynamic loading of Assembly and finding the In Arguments needed to invoke it

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I found the way to load a Workflow Activities Library dynamically by Assembly.

Is there a way to know the Input arguments needed to pass to the workflow before invoking it?

I cannot find any properties on the loaded type that shows me the arguments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using XAML instead of compiled Assembly.

That way I could cast it as a DynamicActivity and pull out the Properties that shows the InArguements.